# Running entire C++ pipeline as blackbox from R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a [.cpp file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47464062/imtd.cpp) (a class I think) that I consider as a blackbox: it just requires a [.txt file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47464062/edgelist.txt) in a specific format as input, and it writes another [.txt file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47464062/edgelist-out.txt) as output.

How can I use this code from within R? The `Rcpp` package seems like the way to go, but from browsing the web all the answers/posts I have seen deal with calling a single C++ function from R (e.g., with `// [[Rcpp::export]]`). But in my case, I'm not interested in a specific function. I just want to run the entire C++ script as a blackbox...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Independently of R, compile it with your C++ compiler

```
g++ imtd.cpp -o imtd
```

producing an executable and then create an R program to produce the input file, `edgelist.txt`, run the executable using the R `shell` command and read the output file `edgelist-out.txt` back in:

```
shell("imtd edgelist")

# read edgelist-out.txt into R
# - the first field of the first line contains the number of triangles
# - lines containing a comma have 3 fields separated by one or more punctuation characters
# - there are some class counts at the end which we recompute rather than read

L <- readLines("edgelist-out.txt")

no.of.triangles <- read.table(text = L, nrow = 1)[[1]] 

# extract lines with a comma, replace punctuation with space & create 3 column data frame
DF <- read.table(text = gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", grep(",", L, value = TRUE)))

# rather than read in the class counts compute them from DF
tab <- table(DF$V3) # table of class counts
```

You don't need Rcpp for this.  The above allows treating the `imtd.cpp` file as a black box knowing only the formats of the input and output files, as requested.

Comment: excellent. Many thanks. Let me try this first thing in the morning tomorrow after what I will accept your answer.

Comment: Of course this works, but calling external executables is the crudest and least efficient form. If it is good enough for you, fine -- otherwise you *do* have the code to call, and Rcpp to provide an interface.